# Validate presence of attributes on edit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, carrierwave

This is a complicated one so I will try to explain as best as I can. I have an attachment model and I am using carrierwave_direct as the gem. Carrierwave_direct requires uploading on one page and then the attributes on another page. The other page it needs to redirect you to is the edit page, however the attributes on the edit page I cannot validate through the model, unless I want the upload to fail(because it won't create an id with validations meant for another page.).  I think what I am saying is how would I validate that model attributes have a presence only on the edit page and if the user exits the page without filling in the form, it deletes the model instance. I want it to do this because for my model to work they need it to create the model instance on upload. See my code in the controller below

```
  def edit
    @attachment = Attachment.find(params[:id])
  end

  def report_uploader
    @uploader = Attachment.new.delivery
    @uploader.success_action_redirect = uploaded_attachments_url
    @uploader
  end

  helper_method :report_uploader

  def after_upload
    @attachment = Attachment.new(recruiter_id: current_user.id, uploader_name: current_user.first_name + " " + current_user.last_name)
    @recruiter = current_user
    @attachment.url = @attachment.delivery.direct_fog_url + params[:key]
    @attachment.key = params[:key]
    @attachment.filename = File.basename(@attachment.key)
    @attachment.save

    redirect_to edit_attachment_path(id: @attachment.id, :anchor => 'reports')
  end
```

attachment modal

```
.head
    %h2 Add Attachment
    .close
      %a{:href=>"#",:rel=>"modal:close"} &#10062;
  .content
    = direct_upload_form_for report_uploader , :html => { :class => "standard" } do |f|
      .fieldgroup.upload
        .field
          .upload
            = link_to "#", class: "btn primary" do
              = image_tag 'loader-white.gif', alt: 'Loading', class: 'loading'
              Upload Attachment
            = f.file_field :delivery, class: 'file_upload', id: 'upload_attachment'
```

edit page(User is redirected here)

```
.content
  %h2 Add Some Additional Stuff to your Attachment!
  = form_for @attachment, html: {class: "standard manage-job"} do |f|
    .fieldgroup.upload
      .field
        Your Attachment Title
        %br
        %a{href:  attachment_path(id: @attachment.id),  target: '_blank' }
          = @attachment.filename
      .field
        %select{name: "attachment[attachment_type]"}
          %option{value: ""} Select Attachment Type
          %option{value: "Type A"} Type A
          %option{value: "Type B"} Type B
          %option{value: "Type C"} Type C       
      .field
        Description of your Attachment
        = f.text_area :description 
      .actions
        = f.submit "Submit Report", class: "btn primary"  

= link_to 'Cancel', attachments_path
```

Comment: Find a field that CarrierWave fills in only after validation and scope all other validations only when this field is not null. Or add an attribute to do something similar for you.

Comment: Alternatively you can use some javascript magic to make upload work inline so you save whole model in one request. Example http://pjambet.github.io/blog/direct-upload-to-s3/

Comment: unfortunately I can't get it to work with the new Carrierwave Direct. It uses a Uploader action that for some reason won't let me do the same things.